# Jmeter WebDriver Sampler script with intellisense support

Tags: groovy, scripting, jmeter, intellisense

I sort of understand that Jmeter is a load testing tool and is not pretending to be a full IDE (as Visual Studio or Eclipse). I've been scripting in Jmeter **WebDriver Sampler** with the **groovy** language for a little while now, and would love to locate this functionality (if it exists of course) as intellisense support while typing. So far my approach is as follow:

1. Create Thread Group
2. Add Chrome Driver Config & HTTP Cookie Manager
3. Add WebDriver Sampler with the groovy language chosen
4. Under sampler, add Config Element => User Defined Variables

In that **User Defined Variables** window I declare all my web elements that I need for my groovy script. While typing the script itself, I have to switch between windows in order to type web elements variables correctly (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), which is pretty annoying after 10 - 15 minutes of work.

My question is: do we have a way to add an intellisense support for groovy language that would recognize those WDS.browser methods as well as defined variables? I researched online as well as **Plugins Manager**, but couldn't find anything related to that. Hope someone will help.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone? Do you have to come across any project that offers intellisense support for Jmeter?

Comment: From what I've learned, the plugin  can be developed, but as of right now, it doesn't exist...

Comment: Anyone has updates on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter does not have intellisense support. Optionally you can do your scripting in external editor that supports intellisense like eclipse or vs code and reference your script file in JMeter. See reference below from `JSR223 Post Processor`

[image]